# Constructors error. Google not helping

Tags: java

Basically my task is to get a bunch of elements in an array and do various tasks with them such as find the shortest/longest element etc.

Now what I'm stuck on is probably something wrong with my constructor.

What I have to do is make a constructor that has a single string array as an argument.

What I'm trying to do is getting the average length of words in a sentence. My code so far:

```
public class Sentence {
private static String[] words = new String[50]; //Instance variable that holds words.

public Sentence(String[] array){ // My Constructor. (If that is right?)
}

    public double meanLength(String str) { //Method for sorting words.
    String words[] = str.split("()");
    int numWords = words.length;
    int totalCharacters = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++)
        totalCharacters = totalCharacters + words[i].length();
    return totalCharacters/numWords;
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     String[] wordList = {"A", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped",
             "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"};
     Sentence text = new Sentence(wordList);
 System.out.printf("Mean word length:%5.2f\n",text.meanLength()); 
// Now this is where the error comes up.
```

Error saying: 
java method meanLength in class Sentence cannot be applied to given types;

required:java.lang.String

found: no arguments

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Will appreciate all help. Probably have more errors to solve as I'm a very new Java programmer. Such as when I cancel the sorting bit out. There are many nulls when system print.

Thanks.

Comment: please post your actual code. you are missing a bunch of {}

Comment: You seem to be trying to define an instance method inside your constructor. That won't work.

Comment: @khelwood Yeah I have a bunch of other code so I shortened it drastically

Comment: @bob9123 It's not helpful posting nonsense and expecting people to find the particular problem that you meant to ask about. Your code is still incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `text.meanLength()` without any arguments, even though that method has a single String parameter - `public double meanLength(String str)`.

And the method `public double meanLength(String str)` can't be inside the constructor.

Comment: Yeah the constructor is blocked off from everything else. So I do text.meanLength(str) or text.meanLength(String)?

Comment: @bob9123 You have to pass some String to that method. For example - `text.meanLength("something")` or `text.meanLength(str)` where `str` is a String variable.